# How to close GROWL Message on click anywhere on the message? (JSF,Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, user-interface, primefaces, growl

I need to close the growl messages in my UI, if the user clicks *anywhere* **on the message**.

That is required, because the close button of the default growl messages in Primefaces is difficult to find for the user.

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about solve it via CSS:

```
.ui-growl-icon-close {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: none!important;
}
```

Put this into your CSS file.